# Write in file using 20 threads

Tags: c

The Idea here is to create a file to be written to. I'm trying to create ten threads and have them print to the file 10 times each. Using a semaphore to stop multiple threads from writing to the file at once. But I have errors. The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define FNAME   "fisier.txt"
#define MAX_STRING_LEN  80
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 10

FILE *fp;
sem_t mutex;
int counter;

FILE *makeTextFile(char *fname, char mode){
   FILE *localFP;
   localFP = fopen(fname, &mode);
 return (localFP);
}

void *print_message(void *tid){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        fp = fopen(FNAME, "a");
        fprintf(fp, "Thread %d is running.\n", tid);
        fclose(fp);
    sem_post(&mutex);
    printf ( "Thread %d has finished.\n", tid);
    }
}

int threads(){
    const char *fName = "fisier.txt";
    int status;
    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    fp = makeTextFile(FNAME, 'w');
    fprintf(fp, "Process ID: %ld\n", (long)getpid());
    fclose(fp);

    int i;
    for (i =0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &print_message, (void *)i);
        if (status != 0){
            printf("pthread_create returned error code %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
     }
    }

int main() {
    threads();  

    return 0;
}
```

Warnings:

```
probl2.c: In function ‘print_message’:
probl2.c:27:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
         fprintf(fp, "Thread %d is running.\n", tid);
                     ^
probl2.c:30:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf ( "Thread %d has finished.\n", tid);
              ^
probl2.c: In function ‘threads’:
probl2.c:44:68: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &print_message, (void *)i);
```

Writing in a file just it: Process ID: 10568
I want to write 
How to solve it ?

Comment: Cast the `void*` to an `int`, since you were clever enough to cast the `int` to a `void*`. And those aren't errors, but warnings. Still, good on you for heeding them.

Comment: The last warning can be avoided by casting to `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`… so `(void *)(intptr_t)i` and `(int)(intptr_t)tid`.  It's a bit clumsy, but it's a way to get rid of the warning without disabling the warning.

Comment: You haven't initialized the semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I noticed:

You are not initializing your semaphore. Use *sem_init* to do this (and use *sem_destroy* when you are finished).

You are not joining on your threads. The program will exit without waiting for the threads to finish. You can use *pthread_join* in a loop to make sure all threads have finished.

Here is an updated version of your threads function. In production code I would check the return values of the functions I added.

```
void threads(){
    const char *fName = "fisier.txt";
    int status;
    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    fp = makeTextFile(FNAME, 'w');
    fprintf(fp, "Process ID: %ld\n", (long)getpid());
    fclose(fp);

    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    int i;

    for (i =0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &print_message, (void*)i);
        if (status != 0){
            printf("pthread_create returned error code %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
     }

     void* value = NULL;
     for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
         pthread_join(threads[i], &value);
     }
     sem_destroy(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now all it's well :D